# Help me catch a word

Tags: word

He spoke so fast, I can't make out the word he said at 2:05:8.

在既不能证实,也不能证伪的时候, ???(sounds like li3) ...

[周孝正：中国社会问题分析](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5TSmPlXkrY&feature=youtu.be&t=2h5m5s)

Comment: Don't make me wrong. There is beauty in his language. His speech is very pleasant. I only wish he can slow down a little bit when it comes to jargons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ……在既不能证实，也不能证伪的时候，**存疑**。这就是科学精神。……

Comment: +1. Mine was wrong.